# No response form Server Socket Java

Tags: java, sockets

Please help, connection to server has been made but the server willl not respond to any requests. Just trying to get the time and date working by sending the server "1". P.s i know i should not have all of the cases of 1-7 but i just want to get the date ad time working before worrying about any others

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author samdo
 */
public class SocketProgrammingSamD {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private static Scanner in;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Samuel Donini");
        System.out.println("                           ");
        System.out.println("Project 1");
        System.out.println("                           ");
        System.out.println("                           ");
        //new Driver().execute(args);//Creates an instance of the Driver class and Calls the Driver.execute method

        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("(Client) Enter Server Ip to Connect to(Empty will give localhost):");
        String ip = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("(Client) Enter your server port no:");
        int port = in.nextInt();
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0) {
            ip = "localhost";
        }
        System.out.println("Connecting to " + ip + ":" + port);
        // for taking input from client
        // InputStream inputStream = connectionSocket.getInputStream();

        // Try to connect to port and the IP address given on the command line.
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port)) {

            // for taking input from client
            // InputStream inputStream = connectionSocket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader inputFromClient = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            // for giving output to the client.
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            // output to client, to send data to the server
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
            // get output from server
            InputStream serverInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReaderFromServer = new InputStreamReader(
                    serverInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReaderFromServer);
            //System.out.println("(Client) Give input:");

             System.out.printf("Menu Options:\t\t\tCommands\n"); 
        System.out.printf("-------------\t\t\t--------\n"); 
        System.out.printf(" * 1 current Date & Time:\t1\n"); 
        System.out.printf(" * 2 uptime: \t\t        2\n"); 
        System.out.printf(" * 3 memory use: \t\t3\n"); 
        System.out.printf(" * 4 Netstat: \t\t        4\n"); 
        System.out.printf(" * 5 current users: \t\t5\n"); 
        System.out.printf(" * 6 disk usage: \t\t6\n"); 
        System.out.printf(" * 7 Quit: \t\t\t7\n\n");


            String readingLineFromUser = inputFromClient.readLine();
            // sending data to server
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(readingLineFromUser + "\n");

            String getStringFromServer = bufferReader.readLine();

            System.out.println("Got input from server (in client):" + getStringFromServer);

            //attempts to get System Time
            System.out.println("Requesting system time");
            System.out.println("1");
//System.out.write("Server Date" + (new Date()).toString() + "\n");
            System.out.println("Response from the server:\n");

        // Read lines from the server and print them until "ServerDone" on
            // a line by itself is encountered.
            String answer;
            while ((answer = inputFromClient.readLine()) != null && !answer.equals("ServerDone")) {
                System.out.println(answer);
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}



import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket severSocket;
    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("(Server) Enter your server port no:");
        int port = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Server Estabilsh Connection On Localhost or own ip with port : " + port);
        severSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        System.out.println("Now you can run your client app.");

        while (true) {
            Socket connectionSocketListens = severSocket.accept();//Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it.
            System.out.println("Accepted Client connection");
            // for taking input from client
            InputStream inputStream = connectionSocketListens.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader inputFromClient = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
            // for giving output to the client.
            OutputStream outputStream = connectionSocketListens.getOutputStream();
            // output to client, to send data to the server
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    outputStream);
            // get output from server

            String readingLineFromClientSocket = inputFromClient.readLine();
            // sending data to client
            String modified = doOperation(readingLineFromClientSocket);
            // send data to client
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(modified + "\n");

            // Read the request from the client! *** input = inputFromClient
            String answer = inputFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Request from client "+answer);
            Process cmdProc;
            cmdProc = null;
            // Execute the appropriate command.
            if (answer.charAt(0) == '1') {
                System.out.println("Responding to date and time request from the client ");
                cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");//MUST ADD TIME
            }
            if (answer.charAt(0) == '2') {
                System.out.println("Responding to uptime request from the client ");
                cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");//MUST CHANGE
            }
            if (answer.charAt(0) == '3') {
                System.out.println("Responding to memory use request from the client ");
                cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");
            }
            if (answer.charAt(0) == '4') {
                System.out.println("Responding to Netstat request from the client ");
                cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");
            }
            if (answer.charAt(0) == '5') {
                System.out.println("Responding to current users request from the client ");
                cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");
            }
            if (answer.charAt(0) == '6') {
                System.out.println("Responding to disk usage request from the client ");
                cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");
            }
            if (answer.charAt(0) == '7') {
                System.out.println("Responding to Quit request from the client ");
                cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Unknown request ");
                //need a socket.close or Server.close(); or something like that
                return;
            }
            //Read the result of the commands and sent the result to the client one line at a time
        // followed by the line "ServerDone"
            BufferedReader cmdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmdProc.getInputStream()));
            String cmdans;
            while ((cmdans = cmdin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(cmdans);
            }
            System.out.println("ServerDone");


            return;

        }

    }

    private static String doOperation(String readingLineFromClientSocket) {
        String[] array = readingLineFromClientSocket.split(" ");
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(array.length);

        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String s = charReverse(array[i]);
            strBuilder.append(s);
            strBuilder.append(" ");
        }

        return strBuilder.toString();

    }

    private static String charReverse(String str) {
        return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your example can't be minimized?

Answer (score 0):

I have a working version after making the following changes:

I changed this code in the Server class:

```
String answer = inputFromClient.readLine();
```

to

```
//String answer = inputFromClient.readLine();
String answer = modified;
System.out.println("Request from client "+answer);
```

Also all the lines like the following (apart from the first):

```
if (answer.charAt(0) == '2')
```

need to be

```
else if (answer.charAt(0) == '2')
```

and - on Windows at least - the following line:

```
cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");
```

needs to be

```
cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c date /T");
```

This line:

```
while ((answer = inputFromClient.readLine()) != null && !answer.equals("ServerDone")) {
```

should be:

```
while ((answer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null && !answer.equals("ServerDone")) {
```

And after this line:

```
System.out.println(cmdans);
```

you need:

```
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(cmdans + "\n");
```